# How do you test that something is random? Or "random enough'?

Tags: python, unit-testing, random

I have to return a random entry from my database.

I wrote a function, and since I'm using the `random` module in Python, it's probably unless I used it in a stupid way.

Now, how can I write a unit test that check that this function works? After all, if it's a good random value, you can never know.

I'm not paranoid, my function is not that complex and the Python standard library is 1000 x
time good enough for my purpose. I'm not doing cryptography or something critical. I'm just curious to know if there is a way.

Comment: What exactly does the function do?

Comment: getting something random from a database is usually done *in the database*, not python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several statistical tests listed on [RANDOM.ORG for testing randomness](http://www.random.org/analysis/).  See the last two sections of the linked article.

Also, if you can get a copy of [Beautiful Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596159811) there's a whole chapter by [John D. Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/) called *Testing a Random Number Generator*.  He explains a lot of the statistical methods listed in the article above.  If you really want to learn about RNGs, that chapter is a really good starting point.  I've written about the subject myself, but John does a much better job of explaining it.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot really tell (see cartoon).

However, you can measure the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of your generated sample, and test it against the entropy you would expect. As it has been mentioned before, random.org makes some pretty clever tests.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could have the unit test call the function multiple times and make sure that the number of collisions is reasonably low.  E.g. if your random result is in the range 1-1000000, call the function 100 times and record the results; then check if there are duplicates.  If there are any (or more than 1 collision, depending of how afraid you are of false test failure) the test fails.
Obviously not perfect, but will catch it if you random number is from Dilbert:
http://www.random.org/analysis/

Comment: Collisions are more likely than you might think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 2):

You've got two entangled issues. The first issue is testing that your random selection works. Seeding your PRNG allows you to write a test that's deterministic and that you can assert about. This should give you confidence about your code, given that the underlying functions live up to their responsibilities (i.e. random returns you a good-enough stream of random values).

The second issue you seem to be concerned about is python's random functions. You want to separate the concerns of your code from the concert about the random function. There are a number of [randomness tests](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) that you can [read about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) but at the end of the day unless you're doing crypto I'd trust the python developers to have gotten it right-enough.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers you also can mock random function (for example with [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/) or [mox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mox/) library) and return predefined sequence of values for which you know results. Yep, this wouldn't be a true test for all cases, but you can test some corner-cases. In some cases such tests could be reasonable.