# How should I test random choices?

Tags: unit-testing, random

My domain involves a randomly determined choice and I'm not sure how to unit test it.

As a trivial example, let's say I want to ensure that `myobject.makeChoice()` returns `true` 75% of the time and `false` 25% of the time. How could I unit test this?

1. I could assert that `myobject.getChoiceAPercent()` is 75, but that
   seems trivial, not useful, and unsatisfactory since it isn't testing the actual outcome.
2. I could run `myobject.makeChoice()` 1,000 times and assert that it
   returns `true` 70% to 80% percent of the time, or some statistical
   method like that, but that but that seems fragile, slow, and
   unsatisfactory.
3. I could run a unit test with a predetermined random generator or
   random seed and assert that `makeChoice()` run 5 times returns
   `[true, true, false, true, true]`, for example, but that seems the
   same as asserting that random(123) == 456 and also seems unsatisfactory since I wouldn't be testing the actual domain I'm interested in.

It seems that random choices can be proven correct with inductive reasoning of the random generator itself but not unit testing. So is randomly generated content not amenable to automated testing or is there an easy way that I'm not aware of?

**[edit]** To avoid disputes over "true random" vs "pseudo random" etc, let's assume the following implementation:

```
public boolean makeChoice() {
  return this.random.nextDouble() < 0.75;
}
```

How do I unit test that `makeChoice` returns `true` about 75% of the time?

Comment: I'm confused. If its random, there wouldn't be a way of making it sway to stay at 75% and 25% without making it un-random by definition...

Comment: I've added an implementation that clarifies the question.

Comment: There is another question. Your code should return true 75% of the time in which space, I mean in 1000 chances it must return 750 trues.. or in 100 chances it 75 it returns true..

Comment: The difference is.. if the space is 1000 then it is possible to return false for the first 250 chances.. This would not be valid for 100 chances.

Answer (score 0):

Testing for randomness doesn't seem random. But to test for uniqueness/collision, I normally use a hash structure and insert the random value as a key. Duplicate keys are overwritten. By counting the final number of unique keys versus the total number of iterations, you can "test" the uniqueness of your algorithm.

Comment: I'm not concerned with uniqueness, I'm concerned with randomness. Since there's only two choices in this simple example, uniqueness doesn't seem useful. If I counted the duplicates instead of overriding them, this would be the same as solution #2: run it a bunch of times and assert that it seems to be, on average, what you expect.

Comment: @TrystanSpangler - essentially I agree with your solution #2. I'm not sure what your hesitation is with running an iterative test to extrapolate the number of times each of those 2 choices is randomly picked.

Comment: I agree with Tim Medora. Number two sounds like the logical choice. Just do it a certain amount of times, enough for a possible chance to match the choices you need. Within each choice you can have a counter to tell you how many true or false there was, compared to when it was 80% vs. 20% etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written is not decoupled from the RNG.  Maybe you could write like this:

```
public boolean makeChoice(double randnum) {
  return randnum < 0.75;
}
```

And then you test key values to test implementation.

Or you could initialize the random object to a specific seed, that gives known random numbers between [0, 1) and test against what you expect to happen with those known numbers.

Or you could define an IRandom, write a front for Random that implements the interface and use it in the program.  Then you can test it with a mock IRandom that gives, in order, numbers 0.00, 0.01, 0.02..., 0.99, 1.00 and count the number of successes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't test the randomness of your code, test the results of the randomness by passing in or grabbing from a random number store a value.

It's a nice goal to get 100% unit test coverage but it is the law of diminishing returns. Did you write the PRNG?

Edit: Also check out this answer as it has a couple of good links: [How do you test that something is random? Or "random enough'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510937/how-do-you-test-that-something-is-random-or-random-enough)

Answer (score 0):

I second the "decoupling" strategy. I like to think that any that depends on random values, or the time, should just treat it, deterministicly, as "yet another input" from "yet another dependency". Then you inject an clock, or a RNG, that you're going to write or trust.

For example, in your case, is your object really going to behave differently if the "choice" is true 80% of the time rather than 75% of the time ? I suspect there is a large part of your code that simply cares whether the choice is true or false, and another one that makes the choice.

This opens the question of how you would test a random generator, in which case I suppose relying on the "great number" rules, some approximation, math, and simply trusting rand() is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a random boolean, writing 2 tests (one for `TRUE`, one for `FALSE`) might suffice *if* the behavior doesn't depend on the past "random" results (it's not clear, to me at least, from the question).

In other words: if consecutive outcomes don't depend on each other, you might test a single `TRUE` scenario, a single `FALSE` scenario and may be just fine.